# How can 'Global security' 'Custom properties' be modified using jython scripting for 'WebSphere 7'?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal, wsadmin, websphere-8

I am using *'WebSphere 7 Application Server'* in a clustered environment. I am attempting to use *jython* to script the configuration and setup. All well thus far. However, I have hit a road block. I cannot find a way to modify the *'Custom properties'* for *'Global security'*. To be more precise, I want to add the following custom property using *jython*:

```
com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies
```

I know how to do this using the *'Integrated Solutions Console'*, but not with scripting. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
sec = AdminConfig.getid('/Security:/')
prop = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:/Security:/Property:com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies/')
if prop:
    AdminConfig.modify(prop, [['value', 'true']])
else:
    AdminConfig.create('Property', sec, [['name','com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies'], ['value','true']])
AdminConfig.save()
```